# File is empty when uploading via cloud storage api

Tags: excel, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm uploading excel files via cloud storage JSON api making the following post request:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @OBJECT_LOCATION \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=test.xlsx"
```

It uploads to gcs but when opening it is empty

Can you please help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you supplying a POST body with the contents of the file? Go to the Google Cloud Console GUI. Is the file size 0? What are you opening the object with? Edit your question with details.

Comment: I was using raw body instead of binary. Now it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was using raw body instead of binary. Now it works fine.

Comment: Include what you changed in your answer.